# python plotting multiple bars

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've been trying to do it for several hours and I have a mistake every time. I want to create 3 bar plots in one graph. The y-axis is to be between 0 and 1000.
The end result should be this

[image: imgur]

Thats my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv

df = pd.read_csv('razemKM.csv')
dfn = pd.read_csv('razemNPM.csv')
print(df)
y=[0,1000]
a=(df["srednia"]-df["odchStand"])
a1=df["srednia"]
a2=(df["srednia"]+df["odchStand"])

plt.bar(y,a,width=0.1,color='r')
plt.bar(y,a1,width=0.1,color='g')
plt.bar(y,a2,width=0.1,color='y')


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas plot function:

```
df['Sum'] = df["srednia"]+df["odchStand"]
df['Dif'] = df["srednia"]-df["odchStand"]

df.plot.bar(y=['Diff','srednia', 'Sum'],width=0.1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks, i also want to change the signatures from the X axis to the names from my csv. It's in the df